# Issues in connecting to Apache Derby From Play Application

Tags: jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.0, derby

I am stuck trying to connect to an embedded Apache Derby Database through my Play (2.3.9) application. Have the following configurations in application.conf:

```
DATABASE_URL_DB = "derby:MyDB"
db.default.driver = org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:"${DATABASE_URL_DB}
```

(I have the MyDB DB directory inside the Derby installation directory - which is the default).

Following is the controller code (a fragment of the file) i am trying to execute:

```
package controllers
import play.api.db._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current

object Application extends Controller {

 def test = Action {

    var outString = "Number is "
    val conn = DB.getConnection()
    try {
      val stmt = conn.createStatement
      val rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 9 as testkey ")
      while (rs.next()) {
        outString += rs.getString("testkey")
      }
    } finally {
      conn.close()
    }
    Ok(outString)
  }
}
```

The dependencies in place (alongside others):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , cache , ws)
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.12.1.1"
```

In Routes (alongside others):

```
GET     /globalTest                 controllers.Application.test
```

I get the error: `NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`

Could someone point out the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like the class is there (so dependencies resolution worked), but the JVM could not initialize the class. Look at the whole stack trace. Is there something specific that the embedded Derby driver is requiring? Some DataSource specific stuff? Something in the lines of connection pooling?

Comment: Issue is resolved. Apparently there was some dependency conflict. I removed one of the other dependencies and it works fine now. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Maybe you ended up having two derby libraries which lead to some conflicts. Anyway glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by minimizing the number of dependencies in build.sbt. Certainly seems like one of the dependencies in my project was interfering with the Derby drivers.